# Writing StarkNet contracts Error Missing data for required field

Tags: ethereum, starknet

I'm trying to declare the sample contract as defined here:

https://www.cairo-lang.org/docs/hello_starknet/intro.html

When invoking

```
starknet declare --contract contract_compiled.json
```

result

> Error: ValidationError: {'contract_class_version': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'entry_points_by_type': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'EXTERNAL': {'value': {0: {'function_idx': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'offset': ['Unknown field.']}, 1: {'function_idx': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'offset': ['Unknown field.']}}}}), 'program': ['Unknown field.']}

When invoking

```
starknet declare  --network alpha-goerli --account __default__ --contract contract_compiled.json
```

result

> Error: ValidationError: {'contract_class_version': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'entry_points_by_type': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'EXTERNAL': {'value': {0: {'function_idx': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'offset': ['Unknown field.']}, 1: {'function_idx': ['Missing data for required field.'], 'offset': ['Unknown field.']}}}}), 'program': ['Unknown field.']}

my account has 0.00381910303249468 ETH
account is https://testnet.starkscan.co/contract/0x05a8303a0fb86f6f922c7acd0548a282c46d8c532a069dfa7e1ca22f3f3eef8c#overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to declare a Cairo 0.x contract. The CLI now accepts by default only Cairo 1 contracts.
To declare a Cairo 0 contract,you should use the same command and add the flag `—-deprecated`

Answer (score 1):

I will explain to your how to declare a smart contract using [Protostar](https://docs.swmansion.com/protostar).

To declare a smart contract, make sure you have configured your account's private key properly on your environment.

Make sure you copy the private key from your wallet(most of the time ArgentX or Braavos) and add it to declare function command.

You can also add it to your `.bash_profile` file or your `environment` with the name `PROTOSTAR_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY` if you are using protostar.

After you have that set up, make sure your project is built and that you have the .json output file.

With protostar, simply run `protostar declare --max-fee auto --account-address $ACCOUNT_ADDR --network testnet ./build/main.json` to declare the smart contract.